Equations of motion for n-coupled pendulum system
With reference to this article (https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/mobile/folders/1d-IF8FTyizKHbaHXjVSxfaB3bgciqi4p), 
the author uses 2n equations, where n is the number of pendulums, to describe the motion of the n-coupled pendulum chain, namely rate of change of momentum and angular velocity. I understand that 2n equations of motion is be needed to simulate this system. However, I am confused why the author used the rate of momentum change as the second equation of motion, when he could have simply integrated the angular velocity equation to get angular displacement as a function of time. This new pair of equations, angular displacement and angular velocity, would have been much easier to formulate. May I know if either the rate of momentum chain versus angular displacement can be used as the second equation of motion? Thank you.

It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against link rot, please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.
